# Appending to the end of a pattern with a word in the middle using vim

Tags: vim

I have a file that is out-of-date and needs to be updated. The names have changed somewhat and I would like to clean them all up using a single substitution.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
foo.foo_[single word] -> foo_bar.foo_[single word]_bar
```

where a single word is a string of n characters. In the file, they are always preceded by an underscore, but it needs to have "_bar" appended. There is always a "." after these instances, so I thought the following might work:

```
%s/foo\.foo_*\./foo_bar\.foo_*_bar\./g
```

Sadly, the first part doesn't even match what I want, so I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

I would first change:

```
foo_[word] -> foo_[word]_bar
```

and then

```
foo. -> foo_bar.
```

i.e.:

```
%s,\(foo_\w\+\),\1_bar,g|%s,foo\.,foo_bar\.,g
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat but following should do the trick

```
%s/\vfoo.foo_(\w+)/foo_bar.foo_\1_bar/gc
```

what loosely translates to

```
\v             Very Magic (:help magic)
foo.foo_       Search for exact string
(\w+)          Search for a "word" and store in a backreference
/foo_bar.foo   Replace search pattern with this exact string
\1             appended with backreference 1
_bar           appended with _bar
```

or if you don't want to repeat the search in the replace part, you can go a bit nuts with backreferences and use

```
%s/\v(foo)\.foo_(\w+)/\1_bar.\1_\2_bar/gc
```

The most important parts you were missing were

- using backreferences *(:helpgrep backref)*
- using character classes *(:h \w)*
- using repetition (_* is searching for 0 or more underscores. You probably meant _.*)

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot from your post. I figured there was something that would handle words, but the term _character classes_ wasn't in my vocabulary until I read this.

The backreferences thing is also pretty slick. I really appreciate the response!